# Display contents of a file line by line like a teleprompter

Tags: shell

I once saw someone do this in shell. I have a .txt file which I would like to display line by line being able to go to the next line with a keystroke.  The size of the text can be changed as well.

My file is like this:

```
001: hello world.
002: hello kitty
003: the cat in the hat
```

I would like bash to display only:

```
001: hello world.
```

and in a large font so it can be read like a teleprompter and with either the arrow key or "n" it would display:

```
002: hello kitty
```

in the same way.

Maybe I am dreaming but I am pretty sure this was done with only shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=

exec 10<&0

while read line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    echo "$line"
    while true
    do
        read -s -u 10 -n 1 temp
        clear
        [[ $temp =~ ^n$ ]] && break
    done
done < "file"
```

Output:

```
$ chmod 755 script.bash 
$ cat file
001: hello world.
002: hello kitty
003: the cat in the hat
$ ./script.bash 
001: hello world.
002: hello kitty
003: the cat in the hat
$
```

Note: you can go to the next line using the 'n' key only.

Explanation:
1st using `exec 10<&0` I have duplicated the standard input 0(keyboard) to another file descriptor `10` i.e keyboard input is now give to our program via `10` and not default `0`.

Then I just read the file line by line and print each line. After printing every line, I pause for user input using `read` command, `read` waits for 1 char user input(`-n 1`) and reads from our keyboard(`-u 10`) since the default stdin fd `0` now points to the `file`. Once a key is read, it checks whether it is 'n' using regex, if yes it breaks out of infinite loop, if not it loops again until user inputs 'n'.

As for changing font size, that is very much specific to your distro/terminal. You can use the `setfont` command for that. More info can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29328/how-do-i-increase-the-text-size-of-the-text-on-a-console and here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-font-size-831366/

Comment: exactly.  I just made one slight adjustment by adding clear after each iteration         read -s -u 10 -n 1 temp;
 clear;
        [[ $temp =~ ^n$ ]] && break

Comment: Yup sure no problem :)